# R Markdown file won't knit

Tags: r, r-markdown

My R Markdown file won't knit even if it is the default file. I always get the error:

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Execution halted

How do I stop this error? I am using a forked repository from GitHub but I don't thing that has anything to do with the error. Also this is just the default RMarkdown file which won't knit.

Comment: Can you share the URL of the Github repository and/or the relevant file there?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you trying to subset an atomic vector with the $ operator. This $ operator only works for `list` and `data.frame` objects. You can recreate this error with some code like below:

```
vec <- c('a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3)

vec$b

Error in vec$b : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

So, to fix this, you should look for every part of your Rmarkdown file, where this $ operator occurs. And then, **try to identify if the object to which this operator $ is being applied**, is in fact an atomic vector, or a matrix. You can do this, by using the `is.list()` and `is.vector` functions. For example, if the name of the object is `vec`, you would do the following to see if it is an atomic vector:

```
is.vector(vec) & !is.list(vec)
[1] TRUE
```

If the result of the test above is `TRUE`, then the object is an atomic vector, and you know that this object is the source of your error. But if the result is `FALSE`, then you should test if the object is in fact a matrix, with the `is.matrix()` function:

```
is.matrix(vec)
[1] TRUE
```

If the result of the test above is `TRUE`, then the object is matrix, and you know that this object could be too the source of your error.